# Using numpy functions to optimise code instead of for loops for particle scattering

Tags: python, physics, montecarlo

I was making code that would simulate 10000 particles interacting with some form of shielding made of a material. Although it works and finds the absorption, scattering and transmission rates, it takes a long time (20 seconds) to loop through everything and since I plan to reuse this code in other functions that requires a range of thicknesses, it all adds up to my code taking 600+ seconds.

I heard that my code could be optimised if I got rid of the loops and used numpy functions. I have done that and it did bring my my time down to 0.003360 seconds. However, it now produces incorrect results. What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you

This is my inefficient but correct code

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import cmath
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from scipy.constants import Avogadro

start_time = time.time()

def calculate_rates1(material, n_particles, slab_thickness):
    # Get the macroscopic cross-sections and total mean free path for the given material
    _, macro_absorption, macro_scattering, total_mean_free_path = calculate_properties(material)
    
    # Initialize counters for absorbed, transmitted, and reflected neutrons
    absorbed = 0
    transmitted = 0
    reflected = 0

    # Loop over the specified number of particles (neutrons)
    for _ in range(n_particles):
        # Initialize the neutron's x position to be an isotropic step while y and z stay as (0, 0) and set absorbed_flag to False
        x, y, z = (-total_mean_free_path*np.log(np.random.uniform())), 0, 0
        particle_is_absorbed = False

        # Continue simulating the neutron's path until it's absorbed
        while not particle_is_absorbed:
            # Calculate a random isotropic step and update the neutron's position
            step_x, step_y, step_z = random_isotropic_step(total_mean_free_path, 1)

            # If the neutron has a negative x-coordinate, it's reflected and the loop breaks
            if x < 0:
                reflected += 1
                break

            # If the neutron's x-coordinate exceeds the slab thickness, it's transmitted and the loop breaks
            if x > slab_thickness:
                transmitted += 1
                break

            x += step_x
            y += step_y
            z += step_z

            # Calculate the absorption probability based on macroscopic cross-sections
            absorption_prob = macro_absorption / (macro_absorption + macro_scattering)
            # If a random number is less than the absorption probability, the neutron is absorbed
            if np.random.uniform() < absorption_prob:
                absorbed += 1
                particle_is_absorbed = True

    # Calculate the absorption, reflection, and transmission rates
    absorption_rate = absorbed / n_particles
    reflection_rate = reflected / n_particles
    transmission_rate = transmitted / n_particles

    # Calculate the statistical errors for each rate
    absorption_error = np.sqrt(absorbed) / n_particles
    reflection_error = np.sqrt(reflected) / n_particles
    transmission_error = np.sqrt(transmitted) / n_particles

    # Return the rates and their respective errors as a tuple
    return (absorption_rate, reflection_rate, transmission_rate,
            absorption_error, reflection_error, transmission_error), absorption_prob

(absorption_rate, reflection_rate, transmission_rate,absorption_error, reflection_error, transmission_error), absorption_prob = calculate_rates1("Water", 10000, 10)

print((absorption_rate, reflection_rate, transmission_rate,
            absorption_error, reflection_error, transmission_error), absorption_prob)

end_time = time.time()
runtime = end_time - start_time
print("Runtime: {:.6f} seconds".format(runtime))
```

Here is my efficient, but wrong code

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import cmath
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from scipy.constants import Avogadro

start_time = time.time()

def calculate_rates2(material, n_particles, slab_thickness):
    # Get the macroscopic cross-sections and total mean free path for the given material
    _, macro_absorption, macro_scattering, total_mean_free_path = calculate_properties(material)

    # Generate all isotropic steps at once
    steps = random_isotropic_step(total_mean_free_path, n_particles)

    # Initialize counters for absorbed, transmitted, and reflected neutrons
    absorbed = 0
    transmitted = 0
    reflected = 0

    # Pre-compute the absorption probability
    absorption_prob = macro_absorption / (macro_absorption + macro_scattering)

    # Calculate the paths for all particles
    positions = (-total_mean_free_path * np.log(np.random.rand(n_particles)), np.zeros(n_particles), np.zeros(n_particles))
    positions += steps

    # Check which particles are absorbed, transmitted, or reflected
    absorbed = np.sum(np.random.rand(n_particles) < absorption_prob)
    transmitted = np.sum(positions[0] > slab_thickness)
    reflected = np.sum(positions[0] < 0)

    # Calculate the absorption, reflection, and transmission rates
    absorption_rate = absorbed / n_particles
    reflection_rate = reflected / n_particles
    transmission_rate = transmitted / n_particles

    # Calculate the statistical errors for each rate
    absorption_error = np.sqrt(absorbed) / n_particles
    reflection_error = np.sqrt(reflected) / n_particles
    transmission_error = np.sqrt(transmitted) / n_particles

    # Return the rates and their respective errors as a tuple
    return (absorption_rate, reflection_rate, transmission_rate,
            absorption_error, reflection_error, transmission_error), absorption_prob

(absorption_rate, reflection_rate, transmission_rate,
            absorption_error, reflection_error, transmission_error), absorption_prob= calculate_rates2("Water", 10000, 10)

print((absorption_rate, reflection_rate, transmission_rate,
            absorption_error, reflection_error, transmission_error), absorption_prob)

end_time = time.time()
runtime = end_time - start_time
print("Runtime: {:.6f} seconds".format(runtime))
```

The macro_absorption, macro_scattering and total_mean_free_path from calculate properties is producing these values: 0.022236254925269077 3.443076153491754 0.28857427040952033

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're getting incorrect results with the second method because it doesn't account for the stop conditions. I've personally had an easier time using numba instead of vectorized numpy for these kind of Monte Carlo methods. Also, if you could reformat your code into a [mre], it would make it much easier for answerers to help you. You need to include `random_isotropic_step()` and at least the output of `calculate_properties()`.